# ImportError at /articles/api/article: No module named api(TastyPie)

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm making a Django website and I downloaded the Tastypie API. But when I try to run my site on (localhost)/articles/api/article, I get this error:

```
ImportError at /articles/api/article: No module named api
```

Here is my api.py file:

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.constants import ALL
from models import Article 

class ArticleResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Article.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'article'
```

and my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from api import ArticleResource

article_resource = ArticleResource()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django_test.views.login'),
    url(r'^accounts/auth/$', 'django_test.views.auth_view'),
    url(r'^accounts/loggedin/$', 'django_test.views.loggedin'),
    url(r'^accounts/invalid/$', 'django_test.views.invalid_login'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django_test.views.logout'),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', 'django_test.views.register_user'),
    url(r'^accounts/register_success/$', 'django_test.views.register_success'),
    url(r'^articles/all/$', 'article.views.articles'),
    url(r'^articles/create/$', 'article.views.create'),
    url(r'^articles/get/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'article.views.article'),
    url(r'^articles/like/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'article.views.like_article'),
    url(r'^articles/add_comment/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'article.views.add_comment'),
    url(r'^articles/search/', 'article.views.search_titles'),
    url(r'^articles/api/article', include(article_resource.urls)),

)
```

This is my traceback:

Traceback:

```
 Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/api/article/

Django Version: 1.7.4
Python Version: 2.7.8
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.comments',
 'article',
 'tastypie')

Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/deanna/django-deanna/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  98.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/home/deanna/django-deanna/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  343.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/home/deanna/django-deanna/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  372.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/home/deanna/django-deanna/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  366.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/home/deanna/django_test/django_test/urls.py" in <module>
  3. from api import ArticleResource

Exception Type: ImportError at /articles/api/article/
Exception Value: No module named api
```

I don't know what I'm doing that's getting this error. I'd appreciate any help I can get. Thank You.

Comment: I just want to clarify- is there a reason for creating two separate files?

Comment: @no_name: I tried your suggestion but I got the same ImportError message.

Comment: api1.py is the one where I imported the models and api.py is where I imported tastypie.

Comment: Is urls.py is in the same directory as api.py?

Comment: Yes. But that didn't matter because I still get the same error.

Comment: @no_name: To clarify, there is a urls.py file in my django_test/django_test directory and a different urls.py file in my django_test/article directory. Regardless, I still get the same ImportError.

Comment: what version of tastypie are you using? post your traceback.

Comment: @dan-klasson: I'm using django_tastypie-0.12.1. I posted the traceback in my post.

Comment: That's not the whole traceback. I swear I have had this error message too. Did you perhaps forget to put tastypie in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @dan-klasson: I installed tastypie in INSTALLED_APPS but I got the same ImportError as before.

Comment: Did you restart the server? Also, post your complete traceback.

Comment: @dan-klasson: I would have an extended conversation but I don't have enough reputation to do so. Yes, I restarted the server and the complete traceback has been posted.

Comment: Upvoting you didn't help either. In what folder is that api.py file located? If not in root, try putting the folder name in the include like: `from foo.api import ArticleResource`

Comment: It is in /home/(my name)/django_test/django_test, the same location as my urls.py file.

Comment: You really ought to put it somewhere else. But in that case I'd do `from django_test.django_test.api import ArticleResource`